# JS обновление страницы по запросу с сервера

Tags: javascript, клиент-сервер

Подскажите, как на JS можно ждать сигнала с сервера без особой нагрузки на сервер? К примеру есть страничка index.html с js кодом, которая ждет когда на сервере отработает какой-то скрипт

И когда этот скрипт с сервера отработал, он дает команду в клиент и страничка index.html меняется. Как это реализовано например на биржах, когда обновляются курсы валют/заявки на покупку/продажу - он меняется моментально.

Неужели чтобы реализовать такое, нужно в цикле предположим каждую секунду слать запрос на сервер?) Как это сделать с минимальной нагрузкой на сервер и быстрым откликом?

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, то тут нужны сокеты.

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/websocket

Comment: Стоит почитать по-подробнее [Socket.IO](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjA4e7N_dr3AhVWAxAIHd4KBrkQFnoECBQQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fsocket.io%2F&usg=AOvVaw2-f_5gPK9rLqRWpdXGrgVe)/[google firebase](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj347DE_dr3AhUEvosKHQD0DrQQFnoECA4QAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Ffirebase.google.com%2F&usg=AOvVaw3fzCjfkgyYXdUPCdS8VWFg)